# Scheme interpreter - why can't this be computed?

Tags: scheme

Procedure:

```
(define (double fn) (lambda (x) (fn (fn x))))
```

Why can't the following be computed with the Scheme interpreter:

```
((((((double double) double) double) double) 1+) 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it *can* be computed, it's just that the number of computations is growing exponentially for each `double` that's being called ... if you wait *a very, very long time* you'll eventually get your answer (how long? anything between a couple of hours or a couple of centuries).

```
(((double double) 1+) 0)
=> 4
((((double double) double) 1+) 0)
=> 16
(((((double double) double) double) 1+) 0)
=> 65536
((((((double double) double) double) double) 1+) 0)
=> ... ; takes too long to compute!
```

Comment: Or, if you double enough times, it could take longer than the age of the universe. :-)

Comment: can you show how ((((double double) double) 1+) 0) is 16 using the substitution model?